# In OLS, what does a within transformation in a panel do to individuals where a dummy only changes for some?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data

Say I have a treatment variable `x` that takes the following values for four individuals `i1, i2, i3, i4` over two time periods `t1, t2`:

x:

```
    t1    t2
i1  0     1
i2  1     0
i3  0     0
i4  1     1
```

It could be a treatment variable denoting when  patients get a medication for example. Some patients get the medication once (i1, i2), some never (i3), some always (i4). I within transform this sample such that:

$x^{transformed}_i  = x_{it} - \bar{x_i}$

and get, if my intuition is correct:

$x^{transformed}_i$:

```
     t1       t2
i1  -0.5      0.5
i2   0.5     -0.5
i3   0        0
i4   0        0
```

This is what happens in a standard fixed effects panel I think. My question is the following: How are these 0's for `i3` and `i4` interpreted? If I'm not mistaken, OLS on this transformed data will simply treat them as realizations of a continuous random variable. So it will interpret a 0 as something between -0.5 and +0.5.

Looking at the OLS Estimator:

$(X'X)^{-1}X'y$

Where y is then a within transformed outcome variable $y^{transformed} = [y^{i1}_{t1}, y^{i1}_{t2}, y^{i2}_{t1}, y^{i2}_{t2}, y^{i3}_{t1}, y^{i3}_{t2}, y^{i4}_{t1}, y^{i4}_{t2}]'$, I see that the last 4 elements would not contribute to the estimation as they are multiplied with a 0 in the X vector $x^{transformed} = [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0,5, 0, 0, 0, 0]'$. However, both Stata and R will report completely different results if I drop such observations. Also, my intuition tells me that such a treatment analysis should compare the `x = 1` to the `x = 0` and not place `i3` and `i4` somewhere along the scale between treated and untreated. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do this transformation at all?

Comment: to get rid of individual specific constants. Its known as 'fixed effects' or 'individual specific intercepts' in econometrics. Think of a regression comparing GDP to happiness over different countries over time. It will be super positive if you have very poor (and unhappy) and very rich (and less unhappy) countries in the sample. Once you control for the individual intercept, the relationship might be more ambiguous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model

Comment: It sounds like you're concerned about controlling for mean differences between cross-sections wrt independent variables such as GDP, is that correct? If so, there are other workarounds to this issue that don't involve transformation of the dummy variables. These include taking a natural log transformation of the continuous independent variables to 'level the playing field'. Unless I'm missing something in your explanation.

Comment: I solved the problem by now and the post is actually correct, the problem was that I programmed nonsense into Stata and R... Should I delete the question? Thanks so much for your time and sorry for the bother...

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Comment: You can answer your question yourself!  so that it not stands as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the 'problem', the analysis in the question is correct, I simply programmed R and Stata badly.

So the OLS estimator can be calculated by hand, say I have this y vector and I just want to consider the data for `i1` and `i3` for simplicity (the first two observations are `i1`):

$x' = [0, 1, 0, 0]$

$y' = [1, 4, 5, 6]$

within transformed version with `i3`:

$y^* = [-1.5, 1.5, -0.5, 0.5]$

$x^* = [-0.5, 0.5, 0, 0]$

$\beta^{OLS}= (x^{*'}x^{*})^{-1}x^{*'}y^{*} = 1.5/0.5 = 3$

demeaned version without `i3`:

$y^* = [-1.5, 1.5]$
$x^* = [-0.5, 0.5]$

$\beta^{OLS}= (x^{*'}x^{*})^{-1}x^{*'}y^{*} = 3$

or in R:

```
x <- c(-0.5, 0.5,0,0)
y <- c(-1.5, 1.5, -0.5, 0.5)
solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y

x <- c(-0.5, 0.5)
y <- c(-1.5, 1.5)
solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
```